# How do I solve for the selling price?

Tags: calculus, optimization, economics

I realize that this problem is probably very trivial to most of you all here. But, this is a problem from a Calculus 1 class, and I was wondering what answer you all would get. I end up getting a selling price of $9.17.

Anne sells candles from her website. She can get a candle from her suppliers at a cost of $\$3$ to her. The candles have been selling for $\$5$, and at this price, consumers have been buying a steady $4000$ per month. Beth would like to raise prices, but a market surveyor told her that for each increase of $\$1$ in the price of an candle, she would lose $300$ more sales each month. At what price should she sell the candles to maximize her profit?

Now, I know that Profit = Revenue - Cost. For revenue, I calculated, $p∗[4000−300(p−5)]$, where $p$ is the amount of money that Anne should sell her candle. So, $p*[4000−300(p−5)]$ should be revenue. But then, for cost, do I also have to set cost = $3∗[4000−300(p−5)]$, and then solve for $p$, the price she should sell her candles, to maximize her profit?

Comment: $p[4000−300(p−5)]$ or $[4000−300(p−5)]$, which one is the revenue?

Comment: The revenue is the first one. I made an edit. sorry about that

Comment: Wolframalpha gives 32/3 to me?

Comment: Yeah, that was the other answer I was considering. But, I think I get confused because if I do revenue - 3(arbitrary amount of candles bought), I get a maximum at x = 9.17. But then if I do revenue - 3(4000 - 300(p-5)), I get 10.67 as the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this entirely with algebra.

Profit = units * price - units  * cost

$P = (4000-300(p-5))p - (4000-300(p-5))3\\
P = ap^2 + bp + c$

that is a parabola and we have a formula for the vertex.

$p = \frac {b}{2a}$

You can get fancy and use calculus.  You can differentiate the same equation find where $\frac {dP}{dp} = 0$

A handy one for economics is to know "marginal revenue equals marginal costs."

That  is:

Profit = Revenue - Costs

$\frac {d}{dq} P = \frac {d}{dq} R - \frac {d}{dq} C = 0\\
\frac {d}{dq} R = \frac {d}{dq} C$

Note that I am differentiating with respect to units and not prices.  And unit cost is not changing.

$\frac {d}{dq} C = 3$

$R= pq\\
\frac {dR}{dq} = \frac {dp}{dq} q + p = 3\\
\frac {dq}{dp} = -300\\
\frac {dp}{dq} = \frac {1}{-300}\\
\frac {dR}{dq} = \frac {dp}{dq} q + p = 3\\
\frac {1}{-300}q + p = 3$

Everything up to the last line is preliminary and presented here just for background.

Now substitute $q = 4000 - 300 (p-5)$

$\frac {1}{-300}(4000 -300(p-5)) + p = 3\\
2p + -\frac {5500}{300} = 3\\
p = \frac {55}{6} + \frac {3}{2} = \frac {32}{3}$